# Samsung s10e screen protector

Tags: samsung

I have scratched my screen, however, when I look at it real close, it looks like a screen protection was pre-affixed to it... but to confuse matters, unlike other screen protections I had in the past, this one demands much force to be applied in order to slide a nail under it - so much force that I stopped trying for fear of breaking some kind of "integrated screen protection".

This feature is maybe 1/4mm thick, follows the contour of the top speaker, about 1mm under it, and follows the top edge of the plastic sides, roughly 2mm from them, and has a circular hole roughly 8/9mm around the front camera.

Can someone tell me if there is an "integrated (and not removeable) screen protection" on s10e phones, that looks like what I described, or if, for some reason, there was a screen protection affixed to my phone though I never asked for one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to slide under it, there *was* a screen protector, and so I am relieved that's not my screen I deeply scratched in 3 days after receiving the phone :)

So for anyone wondering, s10e might have a protector straight out of the box, and it's damn hard to remove!

Answer (score 1):

From the Verge's article [Samsung will include preinstalled screen protector on Galaxy S10 and S10 Plus](https://www.theverge.com/2019/2/28/18244693/samsung-galaxy-s10-free-screen-protector):

> Buyers of the new Samsung Galaxy S10 and S10 Plus will find a preinstalled plastic screen protector on their device when they unbox it beginning March 8th. Samsung has confirmed that it’s shipping the S10 with a protector on the display, meaning you won’t have to immediately hunt for something that’s compatible with the ultrasonic in-display fingerprint sensor on day one. Now, this is just your very basic screen protector — similar to what OnePlus does with their phones, if I had to guess — and it isn’t glass, so it’s bound to scratch over time. The included protector thus doesn’t have any sort of warranty on how long it’ll last.

> The Galaxy S10E won’t have this screen protector included since it will work with many screen protectors with no problem. Samsung seems to be purposefully doing it on the S10 and S10 Plus to give consumers a quick solution out of the box.

If yours has one pre-installed, maybe they forgot and install one ;)

Comment: From what I saw([1](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s10e/948184-s10e-screen-protector-preinstalled-oleophobic-coating.html), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys10/comments/axzqms/s10e_preinstalled_screen_protector/)), it does seem that Sammy went ahead and installed the protector on all S10e's anyway.

Comment: @AndyYan Very kind of them.